# Table column that automatically calculates average rating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, average, rating

I'm following [tutorial](http://eighty-b.tumblr.com/post/1569674815/creating-an-ajaxified-star-rating-system-in-rails-3) and have models `user`, `hotel` and `rating`. Users can create hotels, and users can rate them. Users rating value is recorded to table `rating` together with `user_id` and `hotel_id`. When I render partial `<%= render "hotels/hotels_list", :@hotels => Hotel.all %>` it shows list of hotels with their average rating that calculates in model `hotel`
**Model Hotel.rb :**

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :ratings
  has_many :raters, :through => :ratings, :source => :users

  def average_rating
    @value = 0
    self.ratings.each do |rating|
      @value = @value + rating.value
    end
    @total = self.ratings.size
    '%.2f' % (@value.to_f / @total.to_f)
  end
end
```

**Model User.rb :**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hotels
  has_many :ratings
  has_many :rated_hotels, :through => :ratings, :source => :hotels
end
```

**Model Rating.rb :**

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :value
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :hotel
end
```

I need to sort list of hotels by average rating, maybe need to add some column  `average_rating` that will be at once calculate average value like that `average_rating` method in hotel model, so than I can easily access to it. How can I solve this issue?
**RatingsController.rb**

```
class RatingsController < ApplicationController

      before_filter :authenticate_user!
      def create
        @hotel = Hotel.find_by_id(params[:hotel_id])
        @rating = Rating.new(params[:rating])
        @rating.hotel_id = @hotel.id
        @rating.user_id = current_user.id
        if @rating.save
          respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to hotel_path(@hotel), :notice => "Your rating has been saved" }
            format.js
          end
        end
      end

      def update
        @hotel = Hotel.find_by_id(params[:hotel_id])
        @rating = current_user.ratings.find_by_hotel_id(@hotel.id)
        if @rating.update_attributes(params[:rating])
          respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to hotel_path(@hotel), :notice => "Your rating has been updated" }
            format.js
          end
        end
      end 
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple. First, you would add the `average_rating` column to your Hotel model with a migration. Then, you would add a callback to your Rating model which updates the value in the Hotel model. Basically, every time a rating is created, destroyed, or updated, you need to update the average rating. It would look something like this:

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
  [ code snipped ]

  def update_average_rating
    @value = 0
    self.ratings.each do |rating|
      @value = @value + rating.value
    end
    @total = self.ratings.size


    update_attributes(average_rating: @value.to_f / @total.to_f)
  end
end

class Rating
  belongs_to :hotel
  after_create :update_hotel_rating

  def update_hotel_rating
    hotel.update_average_rating
  end
end
```

Now you can easily sort by rating. I'm leaving some details out but I think you can get the general idea here.

Answer (score 0):

In the example by @muffinista you should probably do it more 'Ruby-ish' and do it in a single line:

```
def update_average_rating
  update_attributes(average_rating: self.ratings.collect(&:value).avg)
end
```

If you expect `nil`'s you can do `.compact.avg`.

You need to extend Array with #avg:

```
class Array
  def avg
    sum.to_f/size
  end
end
```